# RHEL4 kernel update no longer available

Tags: linux, kernel, rhel4, up2date

I've been experiencing the oddest thing in RHEL4:

When a new kernel version was released:

- The upgrade its listed when I do `"up2date -l"`
- One week later I tried to upgrade the kernel, but "surprise" the new kernel is not there anymore.

Now I really want to upgrade the kernel and don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the satellite repository.

We re-registered, entered a more updated server, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

About the most usual explanation is that /boot is a separate partition with 'noauto' in /etc/fstab so is not mounted upon boot, when you type 'up2date' then the new kernels will be installed into /boot (which is actually on the / filesystem) and **NOT** into /boot :)

If this is the case then you may need to;

```
mount /boot
```

Then run your update command!

If you paste the output of 'df -h' into your question then someone can update their answer. Perhaps it is also something else which I've not covered! :-)

Comment: the output of /etc/fstab would be useful as well in this case

Comment: /dev/sda5 /       ext3    defaults 1 1
/dev/sda1 /boot   ext3    defaults 1 2
/dev/sda3 /tmp    ext3    defaults,noexec 1 0
none      /dev/pts devpts gid=5,mode=620 0 0
none      /proc   proc    defaults 0 0
none      /dev/shm tmpfs  defaults 0 0
/dev/sda2 swap    swap    defaults 0 0
/dev/hda                /media/cdrom            auto    pamconsole,exec,noauto,managed 0 0

Comment: i think the problem is related to the satellite repository....

I been invesigatting , and it looks like up2date is pointing to the wrong server.